# Threaded base class with pure virtual callback, stopping on destruction c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm looking to run a thread in a base class that constantly calls pure virtual method in that class that's overridden by a derived class.

For starting the thread, I've no issue as I can call an HasInitalized() function after it's been constructed. Therefore the thread is started after the class is fully constructed.

However, as the class' lifetime is managed by a shared_ptr, I cannot call a similar method for stopping the thread. If I stop the thread in the destructor, it will cause a seg-fault as the derived class is destroyed before the base and therefore will try to call a function that's not there.

I'm aware I can call a stop function from the derived class but would rather not have to on every instance of the derived class.

Is there a way around this.

Example:

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"

class BaseClass
{
public:
  BaseClass()
  {
  }

  // Start the thread
  void Start()
  {
    _thread = boost::thread(&BaseClass::ThreadLoop, this);
  }

  virtual ~BaseClass()
  {
    _thread.interrupt();
    _thread.join();
  }

private:

  // Will loop until thread is interupted
  void ThreadLoop()
  {
    try
    {
      while(true)
      {
        DoSomethingInDerivedClass();
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
      }
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
  }

  boost::thread _thread;

protected:

  virtual void DoSomethingInDerivedClass() = 0;
};


class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{

  DerivedClass()
  {
  }

  ~DerivedClass()
  {
    // This gets called before base class destructor.
  }

protected:

  void DoSomethingInDerivedClass();
};
```

Comment: In any case you would be working on the derived object, and on the Base, polymorphically. So, the logic to suspend the thread must be called from Derived class destructor. The actual function to implement the suspension/thread closing could be implemented in Base class.

Comment: You should rethink your design. Your DerivedClasses have at least two responsibilities. Thread control inherited from base and your algorithm to do the work. You should split this up. Pass the derived classes via an interface to the Thread class. This will avoid the problem.

Comment: Between I think your design / strategy is not correct, it just doesnt look right.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to avoid repeating the call to join the thread in the destructor of each derived class. If a thread depends on a non-static object `o`, then it's a good idea to have a clear ownership relation to guarantee the validity of the object:

1. The thread should own `o` and the destruction of `o` will be handled by the destructor of the thread object, after the joining.
2. `o` should own the thread and should join the thread in it's own destructor.

You've chosen the 2nd approach, except the thread depends on the derived object, but the derived object doesn't own the thread directly but through the sub-object (the base-object). Since the thread depends on the derived object, it must be joined in the derived object's destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the two behaviours: a class to run and join the thread, the base class for the functional hierarchy.

```
class Runner {
public:
    explicit Runner(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {
        m_thread = boost::thread(&Runner::ThreadLoop, this);
    }
    ~Runner() {
        m_thread.interrupt();
        m_thread.join();
    }

private:
    void ThreadLoop() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                m_ptr->DoSomethingInDerivedClass();
                boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            }
        } catch(...) {
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> m_ptr;
    std::thread m_thread;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use a weak_ptr to know when the object's lifetime is over:

1. The factory instantiates the (derived) object and stores it in a shared_ptr
2. The factory instantiates the watchdog class and passes it a weak_ptr to the new object
3. The watchdog thread can now check if the weak pointer is expired each time it needs to access it. When it is expired, the thread will terminate itself.

Here is an example (instead of a factory, I just used main):

```
#include <thread>

class BaseClass
{
public:
  virtual ~BaseClass() = default;
  virtual void DoSomethingInDerivedClass() = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
  void DoSomethingInDerivedClass() override {}
};

// Will loop until weak_base expires
void ThreadLoop(std::weak_ptr<BaseClass> weak_base)
{
  try
  {
    while (true)
    {
      std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> base = weak_base.lock();
      if (base) {
        base->DoSomethingInDerivedClass();
      }
      else {
        break; // Base is gone. Terminate thread.
      }
    }
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<DerivedClass> obj = std::make_shared<DerivedClass>();
  std::thread([&] { ThreadLoop(obj); }).detach();
  return 0;
}
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly stop the thread, since it will stop itself as soon as it detects that the object's lifetime is over. On the other hand, note that the thread may slightly outlive the lifetime of the being-watchted object, which could be considered bad design (it could e.g. defer program termination). I guess one could work around that by joining with the thread in the base class destructor, after signalling that it should terminate (if not already terminated).